# Facebook Login give me already authorized my app without automatic returning to the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app should implement login with facebook but I have noticed that every time I want to login  ,a screen appears "You have already authorized this app,Press OK to continue" , the question is if I have already authorized the app the facebook should return automatically without this screen appearing as I saw in other applications ?[image]
but when i set BOOL=NO in  this line in Facebook.m [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:BOOL safariAuth:BOOL]; its work perfectly, i.e. the popup screen "YOU HAVE ALREADY AUTHORIZED THIS APP" doesn't appear,but i need this functionality with BOOL set to YES.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Don't want to call authorize function each time when you click on login.Check whether the session is there and continue with logged in condition

```
if (![[delegate facebook] isSessionValid]) {

    [[delegate facebook] authorize:permissions];
} else {

    NSLog(@"seesion found");
[self apiFQLIMe];
}
```

Comment: The session is still valid. But if I do not call the authorize each time, then nothing happens and control do not redirect to facebook.

Comment: AFAIK you need to set your bundle indentifier and a few more settings in your App Settings on the Facebook page to get the desired effect.

Comment: Can you plz tell which settings ? I am a sort of fresher in iPhone programming.

Comment: But i have written the  fb_key in bundle identifier, path is URL types-->URl Schemes--> fbMyKey

Comment: Did you call apiFQLMe to get user information If session found ?

Comment: I am not using facebook query language to get user's information. Instead I am using requestWithGraphPath method of facebook object.

Comment: In the settings page on developers.facebook.com for your __Facebook__ (in this case "My App") App there is a tab for "Native iOS App". You need to fill out the form there.

Comment: I have tried it too, I have filled many field there 1)iOS Bundle ID:com.xyz                                 2)Configured for iOS SSO: Enabled, 3)iOS Native Deep Linking:Enabled

Comment: Hi, am also getting same problem. What is the final solution for this? Please let me know if u get any solution.