# Facebook graph api

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Whenever I click anything with Facebook, a pop-up shows up "YOU HAVE ALREADY AUTHORIZED APP ", even everytime I login through facebook.Can I remove this popup. I am using facebook sdk 2.x for IOS.

Comment: did you set facebook appId in plist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627264/facebook-login-give-me-already-authorized-my-app-without-automatic-returning-to    Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It checked whether the session is there or not and continues with logged in condition

```
 if (![[delegate facebook] isSessionValid]) {

  [[delegate facebook] authorize:permissions];
  } else {

  NSLog(@"seesion found");
 [self apiFQLIMe];
 }
```